# Intercepting CDI beans created with @Produces method

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

In our JEE application, we created a new annotation **@MyAnnotation** that we're setting on CDI beans (**@ApplicationScoped**).
Then we have an **interceptor** that intercepts all the beans with the *@MyAnnotation* annotation.
The problem is that it doesn't work for beans that were created by **@Produces** method.
Meaning the interceptor is not getting invoked.

So if we have this class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OtherClass
{
     @Inject
     private MyBean myBean;

     public void f()
     {
        myBean.g();
     }
}
```

Then the below will work:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@MyAnnotation
public class MyBean
{
   public void g() {}
}
```

But the below will not:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBeanProducer 
{

    @Produces
    public MyBean create() 
    {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the interceptor to intercept CDI beans that are created with @Produces?

Comment: Have you tried adding the annotation "@MyAnnotation" to the "@Produces" method?

Comment: Why do you need a Producer for a ApplicationScoped Bean?

Comment: Your producer is creating a **@Dependent** bean. Dependent is a pseudo-scope and beans in this scope cannot be intercepted because the interceptors work through the proxies and pseudo-scopes do not create proxies for their beans. Have you tried annotating the producer method with `@ApplicationScoped` - it seems that this is what you want anyway for this bean.

Comment: @mtj yes, I tried. Setting "@MyAnnotation" on "@Produces" method makes the interceptor intercepts the "@Produces" method itself instead of MyBean's g() method.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes, I tried, setting "@ApplicationScoped" on "@Producer" method but still no interception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use **InterceptionFactory** (from CDI 2.0) to proxy the bean produced by *@Poduces* method, meaning:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBeanProducer 
{

    @Produces
    public MyBean create(InterceptionFactory<MyBean> interceptionFactory) 
    {
        return interceptionFactory.createInterceptedInstance(new MyBean());
    }
}
```

**@MyAnnotation** should be on **MyBean**.
**MyBean** MUST HAVE a no-args constructor to be proxyable, because **interceptionFactory.createInterceptedInstance()** is doing exactly that - proxing the **MyBean** instance.
I found the solution [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#interception_factory)